# To detect even number using LabVIEW

Tags: labview

[image: Lab View diagram for detecting even]

I was trying to make the even  calculator without using code in LabVIEW but the problem was when i ran the code i get 0 between all the even numbers between 1-100.
I just want the even no in array not 0s.
What modification should i make for it.

Answer (score 3):

Vivien's answer will not going to help you.

You are in right way. Just right click on the output terminal and select Conditional terminal. Remove case structure and connect your boolean line directly to the conditional terminal. 
Please read here: https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvhowto/condacc_valuesnloops/

PS. to get evens between 1-100 you should add 1 to iteration terminal (or you will have event between 0-99).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

[image: diagram]

Comment: The first number in this array will be a zero (required range of 1-100, even numbers).

Comment: To avoid this, just insert an increment between i and x.